# Can't open serialport on Windows CE application

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am working on a Windows CE application which involves using the serial ports of the machine. However when I try to open a port it gives an IOException. Below is the example code:

```
SerialPort NewSerialPort = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
NewSerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

//opening the serial port
NewSerialPort.Open();
```

I have tried to close the connection before the open statement and also checked the IsOpen status before opening it (which is actually false before opening). The SerialPort.GetPortNames function gives back: COM1 / COM2 / COM5 / COM7. I tried all including in a diffrend way like this: COM1: / COM2: / COM5: / COM7:. I can't seem to get it to work.

My first thought would be that I forgot to add something in the Windows CE image. But I can't seem to find anything in the catalog which would seem important for serial communication.

Does anyone have a thought on this?

---

> at
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.WinIOError()
>   at
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.WinIOError()
>   at
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.CheckResult()
>   at
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.SetBufferSizes()
>   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
>   at commtest.Form1.button2_Click() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
>   at commtest.Program.Main()

Comment: Don't make us guess at the exception message.

Comment: Hans Passant do you have any idear about this?

Comment: You need to install the `NetCFv35.Messages.EN.*.cab` file (and [possibly rename a file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2008/01/03/fixing-exception-messages-on-the-net-compact-framework-3-5.aspx)) to get the actual exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Try the exact port name as you get it from GetPortNames() - including the colon

```
SerialPort NewSerialPort = new SerialPort("COM7:", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

// or

string[]   portNames     = SerialPort.GetPortNames()
SerialPort newSerialPort = new SerialPort(portNames[3], , 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

If that doesn't work, try "\\.\COM7"

```
SerialPort NewSerialPort = new SerialPort("\\.\COM7", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The first 2 options don't seem to work for me. I still get the IOException. The last option gives me the following exception:

The port name cannot start with '\\'.
Parameter name: PortName

Do you have any other idears?

Comment: Since the port name starts with slashes, you might need to use escape characters, like: "\\\\.\\COM7", or maybe @"\\.\COM7". Just a guess though.

Comment: I have already tried @"\\.\COM7" since you cant use "\\.\COM7" without escape sign. I tried the other one as well without results. This takes up to much of my time. I wish I knew what I do wrong so I can just continue.

Comment: As Hans says in his comment to your original message: can you give some more information on the IOException's message and StackTrace?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out KBoek. Have missed his message. Here is my stacktrace:

System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  Message="IOException"
  StackTrace:

Comment: at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.WinIOError()
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.WinIOError()
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.CheckResult()
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.SetBufferSizes()
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
at commtest.Form1.button2_Click()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
at commtest.Program.Main()

Comment: If there is a way to give you more information please instruct me in how to get it.

Comment: What is the IOException.Message?

Comment: The IOException.Message states just "IOException". If I would have a driver problem would I still get port names from: SerialPort.GetPortNames()?

Comment: Not sure :( Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446565.aspx, you might find a solution there.

Comment: I have looked at the link. Althought they do talk about serialports I don't find anything wrong with my setup. It might really be related to my windows ce image. Does anyone have an idear how to test my serial ports on windows ce? or what catalog item I need to get it to work. I dont really understand the issue since the application can find port 1, 2, 5 and 7 with the SerialPort.GetPortNames().

Comment: GetPortNames is just looking at the registry, it's not actually talking to the driver.  When you attempt to open it, that's when it talks to the driver, and where you're failing.  The IO Excpetion likely has an inner exception that gives you the native error code.  Since this is your device and you have PB (you're talking about the catalog) why not trace in the driver and see what's happening when you attempt to open.  Are the port parameters you're requesting supported?  Can you open it with a simple native C app?

Comment: The OpenNETCF Serial library might be worth a try since you can trace all the way down to the API call itself and look at the driver return call. http://serial.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have the answer to this yet but make sure you are using latest .NET CF version which is 3.5.  There was a bug in the .NET CF 2.0 version that IOException created upon opening the serial port.  if you look up the bug fixed under .NET CF 2.0 SP you will see these mentioned.